# Twilio: call multiple phone numbers at once and get connected to the first one which answers

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I want to call multiple numbers and get connected to the first one which answers. Also as soon as someone answers, the other numbers should stop ringing.

I am aware of the solution described here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html

Which basically consists of one `Dial` verb with multiple `Number`s:

```
<Response>
  <Dial action="/handleDialStatus.php" method="GET">
    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

But as they say:

> in the case of calling a phone that automatically goes to voicemail or
>   an automated answering system, it’s likely the call will be picked up
>   faster by one of these machines than any human being can answer.

That's a big problem for me, and they don't offer a solution for that!

I implemented Call Screening [as described here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper). The idea is to ask the callees to press any key before they are connected to the caller to avoid answering machines.

However as soon as the screening process starts for a number, the other phones stops ringing! Basically it acts as if the callee had already been connected, so it doesn't solve the problem at all.

Any other solution?

Comment: Just checking there is no misunderstanding; the issue Twilio mentions is that if anyone of YOUR numbers are answering machines, then they will pick up before any of the other numbers get a chance to. However, you mention implementing Call Screening, which helps stop automated incoming calls. The two are different things, one is incoming automated (call screening), and the other is answering automated (the automated answering machine scenario the Twilio docs mention)

Comment: Im having an issue with getting mutliple phones to ring, can ponly make one of them ring at a time, console shows 2 outgoing calls after the originator incomming call, however only one phone actiually rings

Comment: @StevenMoffat I'm having the same issue you are. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than trying to connect to each caller via `<Dial>` which has the problem you describe, why not [make and control each of the calls separately through the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

That way, you could create a call to each of the numbers you want to call. Then when a phone is answered, present the call screening challenge, then if the call succeeds connect it through to the original call and cancel all the other calls that you made.

The downside here is that you would need to [register for callback events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) for each of the calls so that you could tell if none of them were successfully answered and then do something with your original call after that.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: How would you connect the original call to the call that was successfully screened?

Comment: As best I can tell, you'd have to put the incoming call into a queue, then dial all the numbers and connect the first successfully screened call using Dial.Queue?

Comment: @GraemePyle, yes, that would be the best way. Your initial caller would initiate the calls and then be placed in a queue using `<Enqueue>`, then the call that succeeded would connect with a `<Dial><Queue>` to that caller's queue.

Comment: Tx a lot. Is it possible to cancel the other outgoing calls (i.e. stop them from ringing) when one of them is successfully connected to the incoming call? I can't find a way to do this. I would expect the creation of the outgoing call to give you some kind of handle or reference which you could use to cancel the call later, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yep, when you create the call you are returned a SID, which uniquely identifies the call. You can then use that to make an API request to update that call’s status to complete, which ends the call. Check out the guides on modifying calls here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: Okay lets say you call for agents via rest api and one gets connected to the clients. How can I cancel all other calls. Do I have to store the SID in my backend and cancel them from there ?

Comment: @SimonLudwig That's exactly right, you should store all the SIDs of the calls that you place and when one connects, cancel all the others using the REST API.

Answer (score 2):

Solution about storing SID and deal with the unanswered one bases on status as described by philnash for sure works in an ideal world but not in real life. I just had to deal with such scenario and here it is how I did:

Create 2+ outgoing call via API, to overcame the voicemail issue I added a gather option with whisper, if the person wouldn't press any key (very probably Voicemail) do not connect the calls, if none of the calls at the first step would answer and press key, go to step 2 where another set of 2+ calls with same gather option would be triggered, then if not answered, or answered but no key pressed, move to voicemail.
Initially as suggested in this thread I was focusing on killing the calls not answered based on SID and CallStatus, but unfortunately phone lines have random behaviour, same phone calls triggered at the same time would start ringing with big delay between each other on different phones/carriers, hence I couldn't really rely on CallStatus.
After many attempts I just used a dirty solution of creating an empty txt file once the first call would end and would triggered StatusCallBack url (same url shared across all triggered calls) if this file exist then there wouldn't be a second run of the same url that would mess up with killing/keeping calls.
There would be probably a more elegant way to achieve that, but for my use case, this showed to be the best solution.

Comment: Hi what is the best approach for this?